# Neo4j CSV import being too slow

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I know this question has been asked several times but none of the answers solved my problem. I am using the following query to import the data:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Zo5/Documents/Neo4j/check/import/result1.csv' AS line1
MERGE (p:Person {forename:line1.forename, surname:line1.surname,     nationality:line1.nationality, occupation:line1.occupation, title:line1.title})
```

but the process is too slow. The CSV file is about 700MB. It takes about 15 minutes for 0.01 GB to be imported. I have tried the same query on a new database and the process is a lot faster. Does anyone know what might cause this problem? Note that I have index on `forename`.

Comment: Did you try to specify indices? As your import uses a lot of pattern matching, indexing for forenames, surnames, ... might speed up the query.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because the same query works fine on a new database but I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

What are the properties that uniquely identify a person? Use THOSE properties for the MERGE, then use ON CREATE SET for the remaining properties.

As it is now your query, for each MERGE, it will compare the :Person with all your given properties to the existing set of :Persons to see if they already exist. By narrowing down the properties used in your MERGE, you will have less to compare, though the comparisons will still happen and your inserts will get steadily slower.

If you know that the :Persons you are adding do not already exist, then use CREATE instead of MERGE.

Comment: I put only `forename` and `surname` in the MERGE and used ON CREATE SET for the other properties. This way it is a little bit faster but still it's not fast enough. I have to import about 5GB so with this speed it will take ridiculously large amount of time. There are duplicates in `:Person` so I have to use MERGE